# How do I expend this Makefile to use wildcards?

Tags: c++, makefile, build, verilog, wildcard

I would like to adopt the following Makefile from [this tutorial](https://zipcpu.com/tutorial/) to more generic targets. For example, if I type `make foo`, then I expect an executable `foo` to be built from `foo.v` and `foo.cpp` in a process similar to that of making `maskbus`.

```
.PHONY: all
all: maskbus

obj_dir/Vmaskbus.cpp: maskbus.v
    verilator -Wall -cc maskbus.v

obj_dir/Vmaskbus__ALL.a: obj_dir/Vmaskbus.cpp
    make -C obj_dir -f Vmaskbus.mk

maskbus: maskbus.cpp obj_dir/Vmaskbus__ALL.a
    g++ -I/usr/share/verilator/include -I obj_dir \
        /usr/share/verilator/include/verilated.cpp \
        maskbus.cpp obj_dir/Vmaskbus__ALL.a \
        -o maskbus

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf obj_dir/ maskbus
```

Here is what I have tried

```
.PHONY: all
stuff: $(basename $(wildcard *.v))
all: stuff

obj_dir/%.cpp: %.v
    verilator -Wall -cc $<

obj_dir/V%__ALL.a: obj_dir/V%.cpp
    make -C obj_dir -f Vmaskbus.mk

stuff: $@.cpp obj_dir/V$@__ALL.a
    g++ -I/usr/share/verilator/include -I obj_dir \
        /usr/share/verilator/include/verilated.cpp \
        $@.cpp obj_dir/V$@__ALL.a   \
        -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf obj_dir/ $(stuff)
```

Nota that I left the name `Vmaskbus` unchanged in the second rule as I have no idea how to extract the correct "basename" from a rule containing `%`. However, when I run `make foo`, that rule isn't even executed, and thus subsequent commands fail due to the absence of `obj_dir/Vfoo__ALL.a`. Some investigation suggests that the variable `stuff` is empty, but I'm sure I have both `foo.v` and `foo.cpp` in the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself:

```
.PHONY: all clean

stuff := $(basename $(wildcard *.v))
all: $(stuff)

obj_dir/V%.cpp: %.v
    verilator -Wall -cc $<

obj_dir/V%__ALL.a: obj_dir/V%.cpp
    make -C obj_dir -f V$*.mk

$(stuff): %: %.cpp obj_dir/V%__ALL.a
    g++ -I /opt/local/share/verilator/include \
        -I obj_dir \
        -o $@ \
        /opt/local/share/verilator/include/verilated.cpp \
        obj_dir/V$*__ALL.a  \
        $*.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf obj_dir/ $(stuff)
```

Comment: Heh, I was writing an answer.  A few notes; you should _never_ use `make` directly in a recipe.  Always use the `$(MAKE)` variable instead.  Second, you probably want to set some variables for the compiler and some of the flags just to make them easier to manage.  Finally, your `clean` rule deletes the `obj_dir` directory but you have nothing in your makefile that creates it again: you probably want to add that so you don't have to do it by hand.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for the suggestions! I just need to point out that `obj_dir` will be auto-created by `verilator`. BTW, please finish your answer now that you have started writing so that you can explain the points more concretely. I will upvote and accept it if your solution is better than mine (and I believe it definitely will)!